# Unable to install zope.interface 3.6.1 in python

Tags: python

I am unable to install zope.interface 3.6.1 in Python for Windows. If any one know about this please help me?

Comment: No-one can help until you give a better description. Why can't you install it, what have you tried/are trying and what error message are you getting?

Comment: Thanks Tim, i am installing Scrapy in python for window and i read thiswhole  document http://doc.scrapy.org/intro/install.html#intro-install-step1. but in this document they forgot to mention how to install zope.interface and i searched it every where i am unable to find how to install it...

Comment: I think you're missing http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Answer (score 2):

in a command prompt go to install zope.interface 3.6.1 folder

write "SETUP.py install"

it will install

Comment: if zope.interface 3.6.1 is zipped first unzip it, and then go into the zope.interface 3.6.1 folder directory and just run command "python SETUP.PY install"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install it. After you download the file zope.interface-3.8.0-py2.7-win32.egg, you unzip it then copy the two directories EGG-INFO and zope into the Python27. It works fine.